# How to impute values before merging two dataframes in python pandas to avoid loss of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2` which can be seen below:

```
df1

      name  posteam   down      rush
0   A.Ekeler    LAC   1.0       35.7
1   A.Ekeler    LAC   2.0       15.1
2   A.Ekeler    LAC   3.0       15.9
3   A.Ekeler    LAC   4.0       0.4
4   A.Jones     GB    1.0       105.1
5   A.Jones     GB    2.0       79.2
6   A.Jones     GB    3.0       8.1
7   A.Jones     GB    4.0       1.0
```

```
df2

    name      posteam   down    passes
0   A.Ekeler    LAC     1.0     122.8
1   A.Ekeler    LAC     2.0     63.2
2   A.Ekeler    LAC     3.0     39.0
3   A.Ekeler    LAC     4.0     -1.0
4   A.Jones     GB      1.0     43.7
5   A.Jones     GB      2.0     52.0
6   A.Jones     GB      3.0     10.4
```

I would like to merge them on the rows `name`, `posteam`, and `down`. However, some of the values under `name` have data for `down == 4` in `df1` but not `df2` (Look at A.Jones. One df has  `down == 4` data, the other doesn't). When I merge, since I'm merging with `down`, the values on `down == 4` disappear, like so:

```
merged = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['name','posteam','down'])

    name       posteam  down    rush    passes
0   A.Ekeler    LAC     1.0     35.7    122.8
1   A.Ekeler    LAC     2.0     15.1    63.2
2   A.Ekeler    LAC     3.0     15.9    39.0
3   A.Ekeler    LAC     4.0     0.4     -1.0
4   A.Jones     GB      1.0     105.1   43.7
5   A.Jones     GB      2.0     79.2    52.0
6   A.Jones     GB      3.0     8.1     10.4
```

Player `A.Jones` had data for `down == 4` in `df1` but not `df2`. How can I impute a `0` for players that don't have data in one of the dfs so that they don't disappear when I merge? Like this (look at index 7):

```
df2

    name      posteam   down    passes
0   A.Ekeler    LAC     1.0     122.8
1   A.Ekeler    LAC     2.0     63.2
2   A.Ekeler    LAC     3.0     39.0
3   A.Ekeler    LAC     4.0     -1.0
4   A.Jones     GB      1.0     43.7
5   A.Jones     GB      2.0     52.0
6   A.Jones     GB      3.0     10.4
7   A.Jones     GB      4.0     0.0
```

So when I merge, I will get keep the `down == 4` data from `df1`, like so (look at index 7):

```
merged = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['name','posteam,'down])

    name       posteam  down    rush    passes
0   A.Ekeler    LAC     1.0     35.7    122.8
1   A.Ekeler    LAC     2.0     15.1    63.2
2   A.Ekeler    LAC     3.0     15.9    39.0
3   A.Ekeler    LAC     4.0     0.4     -1.0
4   A.Jones     GB      1.0     105.1   43.7
5   A.Jones     GB      2.0     79.2    52.0
6   A.Jones     GB      3.0     8.1     10.4
7   A.Jones     GB      4.0     1.0     0.0
```

I tried taking `down` out of the merge, but that messed everything up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, 
                    how='outer', 
                    on=['name', 'posteam', 'down']).fillna(value=0.0)
```